# Efficently simulate rolling weighted dice (or traversing a weighted graph), with frequent updates

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

I have a weighted, directed graph which is dense with around 20,000 nodes.

1. Given an node in the graph, I choose an adjacent node randomly with a probability related to the relative weights.
2. After each choice, I receive feedback about whether the choice was good or bad, and update the network. For example, after a bad choice I decrease the weight of *all edges* pointing to the chosen node.

I learned [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745607/random-walks-in-directed-graphs-networks) about the [alias method](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/) for simulating rolling a weighted die, which is the same as making one choice (each node is one weighted die, and the sides correspond to other nodes). One roll is highly efficient, but updating the weights is not; the alias method may not be appropriate because I will be updating more dice than I will be rolling!

**What data structure should I use, which allows for frequent updates, and what corresponding algorithm is best for making the choices?**

---

Some ideas/notes:

- I can decrease updates by recording each weight adjustment, and then only actually updating a node/die when necessary (i.e. directly before a roll). But I'd still be precomputing the alias data once for *each* roll.
- Instead, I could simply store the graph as is (so that updates are cheap) and forgo the alias method. I would calculate relative weights on the fly before each roll (binary search works here).
- An additional benefit of calculating relative weights on the fly is that I could factor out out the "global weight" for each node to further reduce updates. Then, a bad choice would result in only 2 updates: the incoming edge weight and the node's global weight.
- *added*: Maybe there is something in between: a way to maintain local relative weights in a data structure (e.g. tree or alias method) and then during each roll merge them with "global weights" on the fly.

The truth is that in practice I don't need to make choices very often (no more than once a minute), so I don't *need* the most efficient solution. But this is a fun side project and I'm interested in finding a theoretically optimal solution.

Comment: What sorts of updates are you making to the weights?  Are you recomputing all weights, just one weight, half the weights, etc.?

Comment: @templatetypedef "For example, after a bad choice I decrease the weight of all edges pointing to the chosen node." In addition, when using the alias method (or with precomputed probabilities for a binary search), changing one outgoing weight means recomputing all of the alias info (or probabilities, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with log(k) complexity where k is number of faces in the dice.

for one particular node let p1, p2, ..., pk be the relative probabilities. Let p1+p2,...,+pk = p.

Construct a tree structure with these relative probabilities as leaves. the parent of each non-leaf node is sum of relative probabilities of of their children. To "roll a dice" draw a random value between 0 and p, and follow it through the tree. When you want to update relative probability of a dice face, just change the corresponding leaf node value and propagate it up through the tree.

In this way you can choose a random value with one random number with log(k) steps needed to find the leaf corresponding to the random number, and when you update one leaf it takes log(k) time to update the tree.

This is a very simple description of solution and let me know if you need complete description. I am sure it works, but not sure if this is efficient enough for you needs.

to summarize, this algorithm needs:
1. Only one random number between 0 and p
2. O(log(k)) complexity to "roll the dice" (i.e. find the next node) where k is the number of faces in the dice
3. O(log(k)) to "update the dice" of a given node. If there are m edges from the original node, then complexity is O(log(k1))+O(log(k2))...O((km)) where k1, k2, ... km are connectivity of adjacent nodes.

```
====Tree Example====
```

If there are 4 faces to the dice and the relative probabilities are 1:50, 2:80, 3:20, 4:70 construct the tree as follows:

```
          220
       /       \
    130         90
   /   \      /    \
 50    80    20    70
  |    |     |      |
  1    2     3      4
```

Generate a random number v between 0 and 220. If it is v=100: take the left route (since 100<130) and then take the right route (since 100>80) and update v = v-80 = 20. Since we are at leaf declare o/p i.e. 2

If v=210: left and v=v-130=80, left v=v-70=10, return leaf=4

If 4 changes to 60, change 70 to 60, 90 to 80 and 220 to 210.

```
==== Lazy update variation ====
```

Whenever weights are changed don't update the tree immediately. Instead, just mark it as a "dirty weight" wait until you need to make prediction from this particular node.

When you need to make a prediction from a particular node and if some of the weights are dirty, either a. update the tree with only dirty nodes or b. update the whole tree. If the number of dirty weights is t and number of total weights k, if t*log(k) < k, then only update the tree corresponding to dirty weights ( t*O(k)) otherwise update the whole tree (O(k)).

Comment: This simulates the die roll in O(log n) time and in the worst case takes O(n log n) to do updates, meaning that in the worst case it's slower than the alias method.

Comment: @ElKamina Yes I follow you. If I build and maintain the tree, then it is potentially thousands of updates per roll (since I want to update the "global" weight of a node, which is incorporated into each tree). It may be better to build the tree from the weights before each roll, and if so then the global weights can be stored in a central location and be updated only once per roll, which is a further benefit. Maybe there is a middle-ground where I maintain individual die weights in a tree, and then merge it efficiently with a second "global" weight tree before each roll. Thoughts?

Comment: @templatetypedef Correct me if I am wrong, alias method is O(n) for update. So, in comparison my method does worse for rolling dice (O(log(n) vs O(1)), but is very efficient to update (O(log(n)) vs O(n))

Comment: @jmilloy Need clarification. Let us say pij is the relative probability for going from i to j. When you update weights for j are you performing same transformation to all p*j s? (Eg. pij = pij/2 for all i ?). If that is the case I will try to improve the solution. Otherwise, if you are performing non-identical transformations, the best theoretically possible complexity is O(n), since you have to make those transformations individually anyways. In practice there is not much difference between O(n) and O(nlog(n)).

Comment: @ElKamina That looks right. For a further comparison, without the alias method or a tree (only storing total weight), rolls are even slower O(n) but updates are fast O(1). If I'm storing the "global" weights in the graph, that's n updates per roll, which makes the simple method start to look pretty good...

Comment: @ElKamina Close. The probability pij is calculated as the weight i->j over SUM weight i->x (all edges *from* i). If the choice to go from i to j turns out to be bad, I want to decrease the weight of i->j by 10, and in addition I want to decrease weight x->j (all edges *to* j) by 1. The probabilities all change differently as they are relative.

Comment: @ElKamina- What I'm concerned about is that I don't see this update time being O(log n), since if you're storing the cumulative probabilities then you have to update all of the values in the search tree above the probability that was changed as well, leading to O(n log n) work with a naive implementation and O(n) work with an optimized implementation.  This doesn't strike me as much better than the alias method.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @jmilloy- I do believe that there is a way to build a data structures that supports O(log n) updates to cumulative totals.  However, is this really better than just doing a simple O(n) choice of a random node each time?  In the worst case you're doing O(n log n) recalculation, which eats the advantage of the fast lookup.

Comment: @templatetypedef See the example at the bottom of solution on how the tree is constructed and updated.

Comment: @templatetypedef Actually, it looks like I can factor out the "global weight" to a separate tree. Choices are still O(log n) because I can just sum the node's tree and the global tree together. And then I'm only recalculating 2 trees at O(log n) each. Together, a choice and an update amounts to O(n) for the simple version or O(log n) for the tree. I'm thinking I might have to code them both up fully to compare them in practice for this problem.

Comment: I have also added the "Lazy Update" variation. In this variation your complexity is going to be either O(log(k)) or O(k) depending on whether an update is needed.